# get two instances of a class?

Tags: c++

CSomeClass.cpp is the class aka CSomeClass i want to get more than 1 instance of the same class, for example

```
pSomeClass->Somefunction() //<-- CSomeClass.cpp
pSomeClass2->Somefunction() //<-- this CSomeClass.cpp has different values to pSomeClass, how can i set this up?
```

or

```
pSomeClass.Somefunction()
pSomeClass2.Somefunction() //this being the other instance
```

how can this be done?

Comment: Don't understand the question.  What is a "this CSomeClass.cpp"?  Do you mean that you want the . dot operator to behave inconsistently with the -> arrow operator, or are you talking about something else?

Comment: Do you want the two instances to be completely distinct? To start with the same data? To be identical for ever?

Comment: You should start with the basics, find a good book and start from the beginning. You seem to be confusing the files on which code is written with the code they contain and the runtime objects that are built.

Answer (score 2):

Then declare two instances:

```
CSomeClass * pSomeClass = new CSomeClass;
CSomeClass * pSomeClass2 = new CSomeClass;
```

Comment: is there not any others way in doing this? and in your example since we were using new, shouldn't we be deleting it after use?

Comment: Yes you should, I gave an example on how to create two such objects, and from the fact that you called the methods using `->` and not `.` I assumed those are pointers, so new is needed.

Comment: what would be the other way of using `.` and not `->`?

Comment: To not declare them as pointers, I recommend you read some tutorial, such as that: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: @codrgi: seriously, a good book might help you. You seem to be missing the most basic concepts and you cannot really *learn* by means of question/answers, as you most probably don't know what the important questions are. Once you get the basics then it makes sense to ask about particular issues, at that time you will have *real* questions.